# Import Resources from Excel sheet/CSV file to Azure portal by Azure cli/Bash Script

Tags: excel, bash, azure, automation

Hope everyone are doing great .
I am trying to do a Bash Script from import & Export CSV /excel file  for multiple group to   group member as a Service Principle or Managed Identity .
But i do not know how to import & Export file by Azure Cli/bash .
Someone look & help me to fix it up .
I am insert my Bash Script & CSV below here :

Bash Code :

```bash
# Prompt for the Group ID

read -p "Enter the Group ID or Name (separated by spaces): " -a groupId_list

 # Prompt for the Service Principals

read -p "Enter the Service Principals (separated by spaces): " -a sp_list

 

 for sp_name in "${sp_list[@]}"; do

    spObjId=$(az ad sp list --display-name "$sp_name" --query '[0].id' --output tsv)

 

      if [ -n "$spObjId" ]; then

        for groupId in "${groupId_list[@]}"; do

            az ad group member add --group $groupId --member-id $spObjId

            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then

                echo "Service Principal with Name: $sp_name (Object ID: $spObjId) added to AAD Group successfully."

            else

                echo "Failed to add Service Principal with Name: $sp_name (Object ID: $spObjId) to AAD Group."

            fi

        done

 

    else

        echo "Service Principal with Name: $sp_name not found."

    fi

done
```

CSV file look like :

[image]